Platform Events and NetSuite
I want two way sync with NetSuite with realtime data updates. I feel that Platform Events will be the best solution for this but I am curious how authentication works when publishing to them. Also when they are publishing to us. Do I need a connected app or provide them an api key? As far as I an see, all that is needed on the SF side is the creation of the PE and creation of the publisher / listener. This doesn't seem very safe so I feel like I am missing something. I see this article discusses the client including OAuth / session headers but nothing about Salesforce's side (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/pub-sub-api/guide/supported-auth.html).
Any documentation would be appreciated.

I realize the duplicate question seems misaligned, but have a look at the answer which points out the need to connect the listener. This is where you deal with authentication.

@PhilW Pub/Sub has auth as the question indicates. On the other hand recommending Pub/Sub is a bit of a moral dilemma.

@identigral why do you consider it a moral dilemma?

@Olivia Overkill for most needs
